# Strange Padding on Menu Unordered List - Cannot Remove

Tags: html, css

I have a very strange padding on my menu. The padding appears both on the top of the menu buttons and below the second level menu buttons.

I have experimented with all sorts of combinations of margins, borders and padding but I just cannot get rid of this extra bit of color!

*JUST A NOTE: people have recommended (and deleted their comment) I delete the CSS:

```
margin-top: -0.5em;
```

However, I would like this to stay put if possible.*

Unfortunately, I cannot post a picture as I need more reputation points (am a new to coding and even newer to Stackoverflow) but if anyone can take a look at my code below and see where I have gone wrong that would be great!

My HTML Code:

```
<ul id="menu" >
<li style="margin-left: 3em;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="sub">
<a href="#">Our Services</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Solar PV</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Air Tightness Testing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Thermal Imaging</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Wind Turbines</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Energy Consultancy</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Recent Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS code:

```
#menu {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #201f5f;
height: 3em;
list-style: none;
font-family:arial;
}

#menu > li {

margin-right: 3em;
margin-top: -0.5em;
background:#201f5f;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

#menu > li > a {
height: 3em;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 3;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu > li > a:hover {
color: #41A044;
text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu > li.sub {
position: relative;
}

#menu > li.sub ul {
font-size:15px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background: #000000;
position: absolute;
top: -1000em;
width: 649px;
left:-87px;
}

#menu > li.sub ul li {
display: inline-block;


}

#menu > li.sub ul li a {
height: 100%;
display: inline;
float: left;
padding-left: 0.4em;
padding-right: 0.4em;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;

}

#menu > li.sub ul li a:hover {
background: #41A044;
text-decoration: underline;
position: relative;
}

#menu > li.sub:hover ul {
top: 2.15em;
}

#menu{
text-align:center;
}

li{
display:inline-block;
}
```

I thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is this what you meant? - http://jsfiddle.net/kkxga/

Comment: Sorry no, all that has happened is that the menu buttons have moved down. Am I correct? I would like the menu buttons to stay still but get rid of that top bit of padding. I take it this is possible, there seems no reason to that top bit of padding!

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a jsFiddle and show me?

Comment: Yes here: http://jsfiddle.net/ajjones085/gSCr4/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and help me!

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/gSCr4/1/

Comment: Unfortunately not, the menu has just moved down by getting rid of the: margin-top: -0.5em I would like that to stay put if possible.

Comment: You shouldn't ever put CSS in the head and body like this, it's bad practice. Also try to indent your code to make it more readable for humans while your still developing it.

Comment: @AlexJones Problem is in the jsFiddle it looks fine, sounds to me like you have other HTML/CSS which is affecting this.

Comment: Okay I will try to do so in the future! Sorry.

Comment: @user125697 but it still does not look correct in my jsfiddle? ( jsfiddle.net/ajjones085/gSCr4)

Comment: @AlexJones Yes but in my jsFiddle it does - http://jsfiddle.net/gSCr4/5/ there is no padding anywhere at the top here.

Comment: @user125697 I see that but haven't you just deleted the 'code'margin-top: -0.5em;? As I said I would like this to stay put.

Comment: @AlexJones I haven't deleted it, I've just moved it to `#menu` instead of `#menu > li`

Comment: @user125697 Oh I see sorry. However, moving it to the #menu gets rid of the desired affect. Basically, I am looking to slot the black sub menu below the white text, but not letting the black sub-menu overlap the background beneath the blue. If this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

I removed a margin value you had set DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/gSCr4/4/

```
margin-top: -0.5em; //Removed
```

Comment: Sorry, I would like that margin-top to stay put. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why do you need a negative top margin?

Comment: So I have room to put my sub-menu below the main-menu. Having a negative top margin moves the main menu upwards so I have room to do this.

Comment: if you have `margin-top:0;` for the lower menu and `margin-bottom:0;` for the upper menu then you wil not need the negative margin value. It would seem you are falling into the XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem